# Express endpoint returning 404 for POST but 200 for GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, post

Built a simple Node app with Express for an API. Sending a GET request works perfectly and I get back a status of 200. However when I send a POST request to the same endpoint i receive a status of 404 Not found.

I've tested with both Postman and cURL and I get the same result with both.

server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const config = require("config")
const axios = require("axios")

const db = config.get("mongoURI")
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

// Middleware parsing
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// DATABASE CONNECT
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to mLab database"))
  .catch(err => console.log("ERROR: ", err))

// ROUTER  
app.use("/api/stocks", require("./routes/api/stocks"))

// POST REQUEST INternal API ##########
function postSymbols() {
  axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/stocks", "exampleStock")
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.msg)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("POST postSymbols() ERROR", err.response.status, err.response.statusText))
}

// GET REQUEST INternal API ##########
// CURRENTLY WORKS
function showStocks(){
  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/stocks")
    .then(res => console.log(res.data.msg))
    // .then(res => console.log(res.data.stocks))
    .catch(err => console.log("GET showStocks() ERROR", err))
}

// NODE SERVER ##########
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Node server started on: ", port);
  showStocks()
  postSymbols()
})
```

routes/api/stocks.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()

const Stock = require("../../model/Stocks")


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("GET router hit.")
  Stock.find()
    .then(stocks => res.json({
      stocks,
      msg: "GET request sucessfull."
    }))
})

router.post("/"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("POST router hit.")
  const newStock = new Stock({
    name: req.body.name,
    message: req.body.message,
    date: req.body.date,
    isEnabled: req.body.isEnabled,
    type: req.body.type,
    iexId: req.body.iexId,
    currentPrice: req.body.currentPrice
  })
  newStock.save()
    .then(stocks => res.json({
      stocks,
      msg: "POST request sucessfull!"

    }))
    .catch(err => console.log("POST ERROR: ", err))
}


module.exports = router;
```

Here are images of the Postman requests and results
Postman GET 200
[Postman GET 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjRup.png)

Postman POST 404
[Postman POST 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VePc7.png)

I'm expecting to get res.json success messages for both the GET and POST request, however I'm only getting the res.json success message for GET, and I get a 404 Not Found for the POST request

Comment: Can you back that up with some proof? E.g. what does the developer tools "network" tab claim is _actually_ happening? (POST is almost always preceded by an OPTIONS preflight call by the browser, to verify that POST is a legal verb for the route you want to send data to, so what does the network tab say is actually happening?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced closing parenthesis on the POST route definition:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: You are the best. Took over 12 hours to figure this out, and my very first question to Stackoverflow. *cries in the corner*

Comment: Haha, glad I could help! I know the feeling :)